# Reference to Chern classes in algebraic k theory

Tags: reference-request, ct.category-theory, kt.k-theory-and-homology, algebraic-k-theory

I am reading P. Schneider's paper, Introduction to the Beilinson conjectures. Section 4 in this paper is something very formal about Chern classes. Personally I find some terminologies in the paper a little old, and I have some difficulties in following it. So I am wondering are there any elegantly and thoroughly written references for the treatment of Chern classes that covers section 4 in this paper?

I guess elegant and thorough depends on my backgrounds. I know some algebraic K theory and motivic cohomology, but not much. Thank you!

Comment: I see at http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/B9780125811200500070 that the paper has been retracted, but I don't know why.

Comment: I google and find the link http://math.stanford.edu/~conrad/BSDseminar/refs/BeilinsonintroI.pdf

Answer (score 1):

A reference I know for this is an article of Pushin: http://www.math.uiuc.edu/K-theory/0536/ and uses some mild motivic homotopy theory.